# deleting a vertex destroys a path? counterexample

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am working on a problem in Algorithm Design Chapter 3 that asks us the following:

- prove that if the $dist(s, t)$ is greater than $\frac{n}{2}$, where n is the number of vertices in an undirected graph, then there exists a $v \ne s, t$ where deleting $v$ destroys all $s-t$ paths

I have a counterexample:

```
s -- 2 -- 3 -- 4
          |    |
          5 —  t

number of nodes is 6.
distance(s,t) = 4 > 3 = n/2
but you can delete either 5 or 4, and there still exists an s-t path.

The edges are (s, 2), (2, 3), (3, 5), (3,4), (5, t), (4,t). These are undirected.
```

Is this incorrect? I'm finding online the fact is true, so I am missing what is wrong in my counterexample.

Comment: The proposition says "there exists a $v$". Proving that $4$ or $5$ destroy the path doesn't change the fact that there exist another vertex that does destroy the path.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete vertex 2 or 3, then there is no s-t path.

That's what the statement is saying, there *exists* some particular vertex k which when deleted will disconnect s from t. That is not true for all vertices.